# "Subscript out of range" by copy range to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new in VBA, but created some small macros with the trial and error method.
Now I have the problem that I want to copy a certain range from one sheet to the first empty row in another sheet.
I can't figure out why I am getting a "Subscript out of range" error
I have tried several ways (see the comment section)

Can anyone explain what is wrong and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

```
Dim lRowStore As Long
Dim lRowAdmin As Long

lRowStore = ShStore.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lRowAdmin = shAdmin.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'ShStore.Select
'Range("A2:Z" & lRowStore).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("shAdmin").Range("A" & lRowAdmin + 1)

ShStore.Range("A2:Z" & lRowStore).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("shAdmin").Range("A" & lRowAdmin + 1)
```

Comment: Probably range `ShStore.Range("A2:Z" & lRowStore)` got a different quantity of cells than range `Worksheets("shAdmin").Range("A" & lRowAdmin + 1)`. Try doing it in 2 steps: first just copy to clipboad and then pasting into `=Worksheets("shAdmin").Range("A" & lRowAdmin + 1)`. When using `Copy` if you specify `Destination` both ranges must be same size

Comment: Replace `Worksheets("shAdmin")` with just `shAdmin` as you used earlier in the code.